# Multivariate polynomials over finite fields representation with prime field coefficient.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $p(x_1, \ldots, x_r)\in\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ be a multivariate polynomial over  finite field of order $p^m$.

I would like to represent $p$ as a sum:
$p(x_1, \ldots, x_n)=\sum_{i=0}^{k} \xi^i q_i(x_1, \ldots, x_r)$
for some $k$ and fixed $\xi\in \mathbb{F}_{p^m}$, such that each $q_i$ is a polynomial over the **prime field** $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Is it possible to reduce $p$ in such a representation? 
Which could be an efficient procedure ?

Answer (score 1):

For $e=(e_1,\cdots,e_r)\in\Bbb N^r$ define the monomial $m_e=x_1^{e_1}\cdots x_r^{e_r}$. Write

$$ p=\sum_{e\in\Bbb N^r} a_em_e \in\Bbb F_{p^m}[x_1,\cdots,x_r].$$

Presumably $\xi\in\Bbb F_{p^m}$ was chosen to be a primitive element so that $1,\xi,\cdots,\xi^{m-1}$ forms an $\Bbb F_p$-basis for the space $\Bbb F_{p^m}$. For each $e$ write $a_e=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}c_{e,i}\xi^i$ for coefficients $c_{e,i}\in\Bbb F_p$. Then

$$p=\sum_{e\in\Bbb N^r} a_em_e=\sum_{e\in\Bbb N^r}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}c_{e,i}\xi^i\right)m_e=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\left(\sum_{e\in\Bbb N^r} c_{e,i}m_e\right)\xi^i.$$

This is in the desired form.